# Video Player Android ANE - AIR UI Elements on top of player

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, ane

I have an AIR application that is playing videos, I’m using StageVideo to play them.
iOS works fine, however ran into different issues on Android devices (black screens, stuck videos)
Decided to use an ANE and implement the video player native for android.

The issue I’m having now is that our AIR application has a skip button that should be on top of the native video player implementation (using VideoView to play the video on android). 
When I’m playing the video via my ANE, the video is playing however the skip button is not visible.

Is it possible to add UI element form AIR application on top of android native implementation of video player?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it's impossible to layer native components in the AIR display list. The display list sits inside a SurfaceView which you can place other native view's above or below however layering content inside that is not possible.

The only solution that I have found is to set up a Bitmap object in AIR and pass the native view back as bitmap data and draw that into the AIR object. This takes a massive performance hit over a native view component but makes it possible to layer native components in AIR.